# PHP + Xdebug + PhpStorm - listening not working

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I can't run Xdebug with PhpStorm. I think I have everything set up correctly.

php.ini is set:

```ini
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/etc/php/7.3/mods-available/xdebug.ini"
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port="9003"
xdebug.idekey = "PHPSTORM"
```

Xdebug is running:

[image]

Cookies for listening are sent:

[image]

It is set in PhpStorm as well:

[image]

But it doesn't work. Does anyone know where the problem is?

Comment: Did you follow step **2** from the *Pre-Configuration* section shown in your last screenshot and install a browser toolbar or bookmarklet? You can find more information on this on [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/browser-debugging-extensions.html).

Comment: in PhpStorm, top menu bar, there is an icon that looks like an antique phone. Did you click that ? (means : listen to xdebug port)

Comment: Also, just in case, try disabling ufw for the sake of testing - it might be blocking the connection.

Comment: What does your xdebug.log say ? does your server user have write access to xdebug.log ?

Comment: Yes, listening is on, ports are enabled, I use Xdebug helper.

Comment: `zend_extension="/etc/php/7.3/mods-available/xdebug.ini"` — that makes no sense. It needs to be a `.so` file, not a `.ini` file.

Answer (score 0):

Does adding

> xdebug.start_with_request = yes

in php.ini helps? I had exactly the same problem and it was fixed by adding the aforementioned line.